# udiskctl loop-setup automatically mounts the image without asking

Tags: linux-mint, udisks

I need to just set up a loop device without automatically mounting the device. I need to mount afterwards because the ISO contains some hidden files.

[image: terminal commands]

How do I prevent `udisksctl` from automatically mounting the image/ISO?

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.